# Soap Client in Perl with authentication for wsdl web service

Tags: perl, wsdl, jax-ws, soap-client

I am trying to make SOAP client in perl for JAX-WS web service with authentication. I am able to communicate with a service without authentication. But when I try to communicate with the actual web Serivce ( who has authentication ) I get authorization error or soap xml unformated error.

Comment: We need more information. Please post your code (remove the password, and change the URL if you're uncomfortable with posting it). What kind of authentication? Do you need to call another sevice up front to get an auth and add that in the HTTP header? Is there an auth-container in your SOAP message? As I said, give more details. See http://whathaveyoutried.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
my $user="testUser";
my $password="testPassword";

my $service_url='https://api.example.com/services/soap.wsdl';

my $client = SOAP::Lite->service($service_url); 

$client->on_fault(
 sub { # SOAP fault handler
     my $soap = shift;
        my $res = shift;
        # Map faults to exceptions
        if(ref($res) eq '') {
            die($res);
        } else {
            die($res->faultstring);
        }
        return new SOAP::SOM;
 }
);


my @headers = (
    SOAP::Header->name('username')->value($user),

    SOAP::Header->name('password')->value($password),

);

# make the call
my $result = $client->getVersion(@headers);

print $result . "\n\n";
```